# Implementation of ECC operations in BMR

Tags: implementation, multiparty-computation

I want to implement computing ECC operations (i.e., multiplication) in a BMR scheme (secure multi-party computation)

What is the best way to do it?

I found Fairplay MPC - to allow BMR computation through ASFL language, but it does not provide a good library for ECC operations.

Instead, CHARM implements several cryptographic functionalities, but without MPC.

Is there anything that combines the two approaches? (Both MPC and ECC operations)?

Edit: This question is about ECC operations as one component in a general MPC scheme.

[CHARM](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/617.pdf)

[FairPlay](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/project/Fairplay/FairplayMP.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to implement private ECC operations using BMR, then you need to convert these operations first into a Boolean circuit. This will be extremely expensive and not the way to go. Rather, you need a direct protocol for this. Note that there are secure protocols for ECDSA, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that the ECC operation is just one component in the function that I try to compute.
The full computation involves ECC multiplication, modular multiplication, modular addition, hash and Lagrange extrapolation.
I know it seems a lot, but it uses only one ECC multiplication.
That is the reason I try to use general MPC scheme.
When you say extremely expensive is a matter of months or minutes/ seconds? (I don't mind that it will take minutes..)

Comment: Do you think to implement it with spdz2k protocol will be better? (It is working over the ring $Z_{2^k}$)

Comment: I suggest that you estimate the size of the circuit and then use that to estimate the running time.